# Core data crash reason: +entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'DataBasket' in this model

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectmodel

I have different model of coredata in my project. 
Certainly I added xcdatamodel file in my project, it crash because in my Appdelegate I have:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel

    {
        if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
            return managedObjectModel;
        }



        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Model" ofType:@"momd"];


         NSURL *momURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
       managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL];



        return managedObjectModel;
    }
```

and in order to make it work it should be:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }

      managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] ; 


    return managedObjectModel;
}
```

I there anyway to have both methods ?

Comment: Why do you need both?  The second should load (and merge) any models in the main bundle, including the model you specify in the first.

Comment: Thanks @pbasdf, I wasn't sure about that if  the second should load (and merge) any models in the main bundle, including the model i specify in the first.